# how to use FindControl method with ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, devexpress

I Want to get a ASPxGridView within another ASPxGridView i tried to do it like this :

```
ASPxGridView3 = (ASPxGridView)ASPxGridView2.FindControl("ASPxGridView3");
```

But obviously that does not work else i wouldn't ask help ^^.
I tried putting ASPxGridView before all of it but that does not seem to do anything.
ASPxGridView3 just ends up as null. I am 100% possitive that the names ASPxGridView2 and ASPxGridView3 are correct aswell as that i am sure ASPxGridView2 has ASPxGridView3 in it's edit template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ASPxGridView provides many template containers, you should use methods specific to these containers to find a control residing in a template container.  For example, if a control is positioned in the DetailRowTemplate container, you should use the ASPxGridView.FindDetailRowTemplateControl.  To determine which method to use in your particular situation,  please refer to the following help topics:

[Grid Elements that Support Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6770) 
[Accessing Controls Contained within Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3922) 
[Member Table: Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3777)

Also, it can be very important at which moment you are trying to obtain a reference to a control residing in a template control.  The standard way is to handle the [HtmlRowCreated](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlRowCreatedtopic) event and check for the e.RowType property in this event handler.  This approach will work if the template4 control is residing in a row~ template container.  If a control is inside status bar, title bar - use the ASPxGridView's PreRender and [BeforeGetCallbackResult](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_BeforeGetCallbackResulttopic) events.